# VirtualDocumentRoot and client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, vhosts

Below is my vhost conf file, I can access to `abc.matpho.com`, other virtual host config files are good, but with `VirtualDocumentRoot` it just says `client denied by server configuration`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Define DOCUMENT_ROOT     /srv/users/matpho/apps/z-shop/public-com
    Define DOCUMENT_LOGS     /srv/users/matpho/logs/z-shop/com
    Define LOGS_APPNAME      z-shop-com_apache
    Define STORE_DOMAIN_CODE %1
    Define NEWRELIC_APPNAME  MATPHO_SAAS_CHILD_COM

    ServerName server-zshop-com
    ServerAlias *.matpho.com

    ModPagespeedDomain *.matpho.com

    VirtualDocumentRoot ${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/${STORE_DOMAIN_CODE}
    ErrorLog     ${DOCUMENT_LOGS}/${LOGS_APPNAME}.error.log
    CustomLog    ${DOCUMENT_LOGS}/${LOGS_APPNAME}.access.log common

    <Directory /srv/users/matpho/apps/z-shop/public-com/*>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        #RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        #RewriteRule .+ /khong-ton-tai [L]
        #SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/khong-ton-tai$" deny_access

        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        #Deny from env=deny_access
    </Directory>

    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_value newrelic.appname "${NEWRELIC_APPNAME}"
    </IfModule>

    Include "vhosts.d/core.d/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

How could I know what really going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the asterisk `*` in `<Directory /srv/users/matpho/apps/z-shop/public-com/*>`

Then this will run on the cloud!